# Como mostrar imagem em OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Gostaria de pegar uma parte de uma imagem jogá-la em uma matriz passar algum tipo de filtro nela manualmente( sem usar as funções do OpenCV) e mostrar o resultado em uma janela para o usuário. Para tanto quero usar só as funções `imread` para abrir a imagem e a `imshow` para mostrar ( nada mais do que isso do OpenCV) mas não estou conseguindo mostrar a imagem cortada dá erro na linha do `imshow`( não aceita esse tipo de dado). O código que estou utilizando segue a seguir :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{


     Mat image = imread("Imagem5.png");
     int m[20][30];
     int v[600];

    // Pegando parte da imagem
     for(int i=0; i< 20 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<30 ; j++)
        {
          m[i][j]=  (int)image.at<uchar>(i+20,j+30);
        }

    }
    // Mostrando no console 
     for(int i=0; i< 20 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<30 ; j++)
        {
          cout <<  m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


      int indice =0;

         for(int i=0; i< 20 ;i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<30 ; j++)
            {
            // transformando em um vetor
                v[indice]=m[i][j];
                indice = indice +1;
            }

         }
         // mostrar o resultado obtido
    imshow("s",v); // da erro aqui
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

O erro que dá é esse :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'imshow(const char [2], int [600])'|
```

Mas eu gostaria de mostrar o vetor que eu obtive sem precisar ficar usando os tipos de dados do OpenCV.

**EDITADO :**

O meu objetivo é pegar essa parte da imagem e mostrar para o usuário. Que nesse caso seria o conteúdo da matriz m. Mas não estou conseguindo utilizar isso juntamente com o imshow. Tentei fazer dessa maneira :

```
Mat copia(242,208, CV_32F);

 for(int i=0; i< 242 ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<208 ; j++)
        {
        copia.at<int>(i,j)= m[i][j];
        }

    }


imshow("saída",copia);
waitKey();
```

Mas não deu certo. Fica tudo preto o que não corresponde a parte da imagem.
Há alguma forma mais eficiente de declarar a matriz "copia" para aceitar adequadamente o inteiro ? Ou há alguma forma mais adequada de se fazer essa convesão para poder mostrar a imagem captada ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resposta para edição:**

```
Rect roi = Rect(0,0,208,242);
Mat copia = image(roi).clone();
imshow("teste", copia);
```

essa é a maneira mais eficiente para resolver seu problema

Comment: Sim. O meu objetivo principal mesmo é mostrar essa parte da matriz original que foi captada. O que não esta dando certo é justamente mostra-la com o imshow. PS: a pergunta foi editada.

Comment: pronto, editei a resposta, esse código resolve o problema